# Checking values of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do the following in Excel:

I have a sheet with some data (`400k` rows, which is why I used long for the variables instead of integers) and I want to check Column R (which contains ID's) and need to check then against Columns S and T. If R is the same and S and T is different, the code should copy the entire row and paste it in another sheet. The code runs and pastes something but not the correct rows. Thanks in advance, any help would be highly appreciated.

Sample Data

```
R           S       T
1234    Kevin   Smith
2345    John    Miller
1234    Carl    Jones
1234    Kevin   Smith
4567    Mike    Redwood
2058    William Wales
```

Code

```
Sub mySub1()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tbl = wb.Sheets("sheet1")
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    i = 1
    x = 0
    y = 1

    Sheets("sheet1").Activate

    lrow = tbl.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Range("R2:R" & lrow)
        If cell.Offset(x, 0).Value = cell.Offset(i, 0).Value And _
        cell.Offset(0, 1) <> cell.Offset(i, 1).Value And _
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> cell.Offset(i, 2).Value Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 26)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("sheet2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 1).PasteSpecial
            y = y + 1
        End If
        Sheets("sheet1").Activate
        i = i + 1
        x = x + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So, which row is being copied -- next row?

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) Also can you post a sample data so that I can test the code before I post a solution?

Comment: ideally the initial row that has the default values in it and the next one. The idea is to find out every row that has the same ID in column R but different values in S and T.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the link. I'll give it a look to making the code faster and more beautiful. 
The data is relatively simple: columns A-Z are filled. Important for this code:

Comment: I am just interested in R,S and T column. Can you update say 10 rows of sample data in your question.

Comment: R     S          T
1  123   Kevin     Smith
2  234   Charles   Jones
3  123   John      Miller
4  123   Kevin     Smith

In this case line 1 and 3 would have the same ID but different values in S and T and would therefore be copied. The rest would be left untouched.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried to post a picture but my reputation is below 10 :(

Comment: you don't need to post a picture. edit your question and paste the data (not picture) there

Comment: so you want to copy `1234    Kevin   Smith` and `1234    Carl    Jones` across?

Comment: Exactly, and thanks for editing my post to be more viewable.

Comment: one last question. The rest of the entries should be ignored right?

Comment: Yep. It should take the first row of date, loop through the whole sheet and copy paste same ID's with different names. But obviously for every single ID..

Comment: Ok gimme 15-20 mis so that I can test the code before posting

Comment: I might even take longer as it it 400k rows and I need to check which option is better for you :)

Comment: This is a perfect occasion to use a dictionary (or a collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried different methods on 400k rows. This is the one which I found the fastest.

**Logic:**

1. Copy the data to a temp sheet and then remove duplicates.
2. Sort the data
3. Store the resulting range in an array
4. Loop and do the match and finally copy

I am assuming that the data in `Sheet1` doesn't have headers. If it does then change `Header:=xlNo` to `Header:=xlYes` and modify the for loops.

**IMP:** Can't use `Autofilter` or worksheet functions like `Countif` because of the number of rows.

**Code:**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim wsILRow As Long, wsOLRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim itm As String
    Dim Myar

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    wsOLRow = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wsI.Cells.Copy wsTemp.Cells

    With wsTemp
        wsILRow = .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("$R$1:$T$" & wsILRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlNo

        .Columns("A:Z").Sort Key1:=.Range("R1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        wsILRow = .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("R1:T" & wsILRow)
    End With

    Myar = rng.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(Myar)

        If i > 1 Then If Myar(i, 1) = Myar(i - 1, 1) Then GoTo NextRec

        itm = Myar(i, 1)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(Myar)
            If Myar(j, 1) = itm Then
                If Myar(i, 2) & Myar(j, 2) <> Myar(i, 3) & Myar(j, 3) Then
                    wsTemp.Rows(j).Copy wsO.Rows(wsOLRow)
                    wsOLRow = wsOLRow + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
NextRec:
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks Siddarth, it works like a charm! I assume that you haven't run the code on 400k lines?! Can you estimate how long it should take to loop through the whole Sheet?
If the data in sheet1 has headers, what would I need to change in the For loop? Setting i to 0?

Comment: I did run it on 400k rows and hence I took such a long time to post. While Autofilter/Countif/Union took ages, this was relatively faster. I don't have the sample file anymore. But as I mentioned this was the fastest.

Comment: I ran it aswell and Excel didn't react. About 20 minutes later I just quit Excel and split the original data into smaller pieces of about 30-50k rows which worked. Did it took more then 20 minutes for you to run the whole code?

Comment: The above code... no. But then maybe my data was not that complex. I have just created a dummy data of 400k rows

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use VBA, you can do this with simple worksheet manipulation.

Take the worksheet:

- Append a column containing an increasing row number,
- Sort by ID (column R), and the row number,
- Append the formula `=AND(R2=R1,OR(S2<>S1,T2<>T1))` to row 2 and copy this down the worksheet,
- Filter to show all the rows that are true, and
- Copy visible rows to new worksheet.

This should give you much better performance and be easier to maintain.